# Reapet n times each rows from query in google sheets

Tags: each, repeat, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I try to have an output by query -  reapeting each rows by formula in google sheets after match the term (term is text from cell - after choose from drop down list)

I'd like to Select  a,b,c,f,g,h etc) and reapeting each column 7 times.
I have two formulas. 
Now by Query formula on Output i have each row only one time.
And ArrayFormula to repeating - but it works only for 1 column

I'd like to combine 2 formulas below to choose all column and repeat each row 7 times.

```
=QUERY(MY_DICTIONARY!A5:F100; "SELECT a,b,c,f,g,h, WHERE A='"&F3&"'")

=SORT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
 REPT(A8:A50&"♠"; 7)); ;999^99); "♠"))); 1; 0)
```

I will be extremely happy to any help.
maybe It will possible to combine 2 formulas into 1?

Edit 09:08
I add example file to show my problem.

[example google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BG3EMotBwQpZtYZeHaokNI8PNLV6YpEZpkxqmAMrDyg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try reading the [guide on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updating your post to include an example of your spreadsheet so others can better understand your question. The English in your post is very hard to understand; it might be a good idea to consult google translate or have a friend translate/edit your post for you, so that others can understand your problem and help you fix it.

Comment: Hello sinaraheneba. You have right. I will try to explain better my cases. I add example file on google to show my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to combine Array formula for all columns. 
But I discovered that it works well enough as a single Array of range each (D:D), (E:E), (F:F), (G:G).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(D4:D100&"♠"; 7); ;99^99); "♠"))))

=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(E4:E100&"♠"; 7); ;99^99); "♠"))))

=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(F4:F100&"♠"; 7); ;99^99); "♠"))))

=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(G4:G100&"♠"; 7); ;99^99); "♠"))))
```